# How to answer this problem on uniform distribution and expected values?

Tags: probability

Hello I am struggling on the following question:

[image]

For part i) I believe it is false since if $X$ is the the gain then $E[X]=1\times P(\text{Correct})-1\times P(\text{False})$ now you do not know if the coin is bias so I think that this is just a "fifty fifty" guess so $P(\text{Correct})=1/2$ and likewise for false giving $E[X]=0 \neq 0.5$.

For ii) I want to use a similar argument to get $E[X]=2\times P(\text{Correct})-2\times P(\text{False})$ except now you know if coin is bias so the probabilities of being correct or not will vary considerably depending on the "value" of the coin. Now I am stuck. Anyone help me finish this? Thanks.

Comment: For problem 2, I believe your expected gain will be

$$2(\max\{p,1-p\}) + (-2)(\min\{p,1-p\}).$$

This would only be equal to $2$ if the only values that $p$ were allowed to take were $0$ and $1$. However, that is not the case.

Hence, I believe this option to be false as well.

Comment: Okay that seems to make sense to me thanks!